# How to choose between 2 input variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a sample job template that uses survey to provide user input for 3 variables. The variable selection is in dropdownlist format to facilitate users to easily make their selection. I use the dohost in tower_webhook_payload to limit the hosts used to run the playbook.

```
#job template A calling playbook A    
- name: intl_dosomething
      hosts: "{{ tower_webhook_payload.dohost }}"
      remote_user: user00
      max_fail_percentage: 1
      serial: 1
      tasks:
        - name: intl_dosomething
          script: ../script/dosomething.sh {{ region }} {{ country }} {{ state }}
        - name: intl_doanotherthing
          script: ../script/doanotherthing.sh {{ state }}

#EXTRA VARIABLES
region: Asia
country: India
state: Mumbai
tower_webhook_payload:
  dohost: public_access_vms_*
```

However, I now have a new requirement to do the same thing via a webhook, to allow easier batch processing, so I created another job template with webhook.

```
#job template B calling playbook B    
- name: intl_dosomething
      hosts: "{{ tower_webhook_payload.dohost }}"
      remote_user: user00
      max_fail_percentage: 1
      serial: 1
      tasks:
        - name: intl_dosomething
          script: ../script/dosomething.sh {{ tower_webhook_payload.region }} {{ tower_webhook_payload.country }} {{ tower_webhook_payload.state }}
        - name: intl_doanotherthing
          script: ../script/doanotherthing.sh {{ tower_webhook_payload.state }}

#EXTRA VARIABLES
tower_webhook_payload:
  region: Asia
  country: India
  state: Mumbai
  dohost: public_access_vms_*
```

Is there anyway I can combine the 2 job templates/playbooks to use template B if the job is from a webhook, and use template A if it is from user input?

Or is there a way to select based on whether tower_webhook_payload.region is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`default()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) filter to fall back to the default variable name when the webhook key isn't defined.

```
        - name: intl_dosomething
          script: ../script/dosomething.sh {{ tower_webhook_payload.region | default(region) }} {{ tower_webhook_payload.country | default(country) }} {{ tower_webhook_payload.state | default(state) }}
        - name: intl_doanotherthing
          script: ../script/doanotherthing.sh {{ tower_webhook_payload.state | default(state) }}
```

Comment: Nice, did not realise that there is such an elegant solution. This is what I need, and I will mark this as the accepted answer!